# AngularJS - Sending many request using $http is really slow

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app, I have a page with many directives. Some of the directives perform HTTP requests. When the page is loaded, all the requests to the server are executed pretty much at the same time. It seems to me that angular $http service performs the requests in groups and until all the requests in one group are resolved, it doesn't continue to the next group.
In order to check this, I added a simple HTTP interceptor as follow:

```js
if (localStorage.getItem("EnableLogs") != null) {
    angular.module('cnsApp').factory('logTimeTaken', [function() {  
        return {
            request:(config) => {
                config.requestTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
                return config;
            },
            response:(response) => {
                response.config.responseTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
                console.log({config: response.config.url, duration: response.config.responseTimestamp - response.config.requestTimestamp});
                return response;
            }
        };
    }]);

    angular.module('cnsApp').config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('logTimeTaken');
    }]);
}
```

In my C# server, I logged the time taking each function from the moment it was called to the moment it finished. I found that there is a huge difference between the logs.

In the client the log looks like that: 
[image]

Although the client logs shows that the request to "IsSuper" took 4604ms , the server shows it took 19ms to perform the route function (And the same for most of the requests)

Any insight on the matter will be really appreciated.

Comment: have you checked the network tab in your browser dev console?

Answer (score 0):

Grouping requests doesn't sound like something that angular would do. you can test this by having a single request and time that one.

You might be transferring a big response from the server, in which case angular will get stuck when transforming the response.

try overriding the transform message and log and see if it gets there quickly. if it does, try to do a minimal transform to test this theory.

```
{function(data, headersGetter, status)|Array.<function(data, headersGetter, status)>}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

Answer (score 0):

Well as you can see here `http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/42955/`

```
console.log("RECORDED TIME ", config)
```

this line output proves that angular doesn't group your requests it just kinda "shoots" them at almost the same milisecond as the directives are created one after another.
though it process the responses one by one (js is single-threaded) with promises thus the incremental delay.

anyway the duration you're calculating with angular is the server processing time + latency it takes to send and get the message. which shouldn't be identical to server processing time anyway.

It's hard to tell how does angular handles your requests but if you really want to know how much it takes to get a response from your server you can look at the `Network` tab.

Comment: Thank you for your response,
The duration displayed in the networks tabs is pretty much the same as the one in my client logs. Also, I'm using a local server so the latency shouldn't take much time. There is a huge difference between 19ms in server execution and 3000ms from client records that I just can't understand.